# Render Gadfly plots directly to a Gtk canvas

Tags: gtk, julia, gadfly

Is it possible to render a Gadfly plot directly to a canvas? I would like to develop a Julia GUI using gtk which renders Gadfly plots.

I am hoping for something along the lines of:

```
some_plot = plot(x=[1,2,3],y=[4,5,6])
draw(ctx::CairoContext, some_plot)
```

or

```
draw(c::GtkCanvas, some_plot)
```

My current approach saves a png and then loads the image. Obviously not optimal:

```
ctx = getgc(canvas)
canvas_w = width(canvas)
canvas_h = height(canvas)

save(ctx)
set_source_rgb(ctx,1,1,1)
rectangle(ctx,0,0,canvas_w,canvas_h)
fill(ctx)
restore(ctx)

some_plot = plot(x=[1,2,3],y=[4,5,6])
draw(PNG("myplot.png", 8inch, 4inch), some_plot)

save(ctx)
image = read_from_png("myplot.png")
w = image.width
h = image.height
translate(ctx, canvas_w/2, canvas_h/2)
scale(ctx, canvas_w/w, canvas_h/h)
translate(ctx, -0.5*w, -0.5*h)
set_source_surface(ctx, image, 0, 0)
paint(ctx)
restore(ctx)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at Tim Holy's package [Immerse](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Immerse.jl) which does this, which can also be accessed through my package [Plots](https://github.com/tbreloff/Plots.jl).

Immerse creates Gadfly contexts and renders them to Gtk canvases with some additional interactive functionality.